# Mongodb: MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$addFields' in '0.$addFields' is not valid for storage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to merge two array of objects conditionally:

```
await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, [
          {
            $addFields: {
              tags: {
                $reduce: {
                  input: incomingTags,
                  initialValue: '$tags',
                  in: {
                    $cond: [
                      { $in: ['$$this.name', '$tags.name'] },
                      '$$value',
                      { $concatArrays: [['$$this'], '$$value'] },
                    ],
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        ]);
```

Comment: What version of MongoDB and Mongoose?

Comment: @Joe, MongoDB shell version v4.0.25

Comment: You need to update your mongodb to version 4.2 to use  the aggregation pipeline for update operations